# How to automatically set breakpoints on all methods in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

How do I automatically set breakpoints on all methods in Xcode?
I want to know how my program works, and which methods invoke when I interact with the user interface.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. Run your app in Xcode.
2. Press ⌘⌃Y (Debug -> Pause).
3. Go to the debugger console: ⌘⇧C
4. Type `breakpoint set -r . -s <PRODUCT_NAME>` (insert your app's name).

lldb will answer with something like...

```
Breakpoint 1: 4345 locations
```

Now just press the Continue button.

`breakpoint set` is lldb's command to create breakpoints. The location is specified using a regular expression (`-r`) on function/method names, in this case `.` which matches any method. The `-s` option is used to limit the scope to your executable (needed to exclude frameworks).

When you run your app lldb will now break whenever the app hits a function from your main executable.

To disable the breakpoints type `breakpoint delete 1` (insert proper breakpoint number).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I tried to show list of the breakpoints and it worked, but how to set breakpoints on all methods with lldb?

Comment: It's point three in the description above: If your app is named "MyFooApp", type `breakpoint set -r . -s MyFooApp` in the debugger console.

Comment: Thanks it's work now (it was my mistake - I made ​​a mistake in entering the name of the project :) sorry). Thank you very much - it's work great!

Comment: Will this update the breakpoints shown in the code editor? I would like to remove the breakpoints after seeing them... essentially running a code coverage test

Comment: Is it possible to do this only on a certain group of files or classes? For example I only want my classes, not imported/CocoaPod files.

Answer (score 17):

There is many possibilities but there is no way to set breakpoints only to your functions. You can try:

`breakpoint set -r '\[ClassName .*\]$'`

to add breakpoints to all methods in class

`breakpoint set -f file.m -p ' *- *\('`

to add breakpoints to all methods in file

You can also use it with many files:

`breakpoint set -f file1.m -f file2.m -p ' *- *\('`

Shortcut:

`br se -f file1.m -f file2.m -p ' *- *\('`

You can add breakpoints to all methods in all classes with some prefix (and it could me only your classes)

`br se -r . -s Prefix`

This line (wzbozon answer):

`breakpoint set -n viewDidLoad`

will set breakpoints on all methods `viewDidLoad` in all classes.

I tried but I couldn't set breakpoints only on our own methods.

Answer (score 16):

In some cases, it is more convenient to set breakpoints only on some of the methods.

Using LLDB we can put breakpoint on all ViewDidLoad methods by name, for example.

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -n ViewDidLoad
```

Here "-n" means by name.

Also, we can put breakpoints by selector name:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -S alignLeftEdges:
```

Here "-S" means by selector.