# breakpoint for particular groups in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I want to put breakpoint for all the functions in my app. From this stackoverflow([How to automatically set breakpoints on all methods in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275195/how-to-automatically-set-breakpoints-on-all-methods-in-xcode)) question i got this -

breakpoint set -r . -s [PRODUCT_NAME]

And its working also. But it puts breakpoint in files coming from cocoapod, which i dont want. I only want to put breakpoint in my code only. As there are many pod files and it gets lost in those file and then its difficult to understand the flow.I want to put breakpoint in particular group of files.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

```
(lldb) break set -r . -f <FILE1> -f <FILE2>
```

If you do it this way you will have to list all the files by hand, but it will get the job done.  There isn't currently a version of the file specifier that takes glob patterns.

Note, if you do:

```
(lldb) help break set
```

The first part of the listing will show you what options the command accepts.  So for instance:

```
  breakpoint set [-DHo] -r <regular-expression> [-s <shlib-name>] [-i <count>] [-c <expr>] [-x <thread-index>] [-t <thread-id>] [-T <thread-name>] [-q <queue-name>] [-f <filename>] [-L <language>] [-K <boolean>] [-N <breakpoint-name>]
```

shows that the `break set -r` command accepts filenames.  The help doesn't say you can specify this multiple times on a line, but it's worth trying, and in fact it does...