# Xcode how to debug all functions?

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to set breakpoints on all classes methods in XCode?
I want to know what functions are executing one by one just in my classes.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do this ? Don't forget that you can see the stack trace while debugging your app in the Debug navigator.

Comment: yes, because of that i am asking 
I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275195/how-to-automatically-set-breakpoints-on-all-methods-in-xcode
but i just want to debug my functions.
There was a comment with a solution but it's deleted. by using this:
breakpoint set -r <Class Name>
I like it.